# Operator '&' is not defined for types 'String' and 'Control'

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i'm building a VB.Net app to check in real time the state of machines in a production area. I want to display in a monitor the area layout and if the state of the machine is 1 put it with green colour, if it's 2 with red, and if it's something else put orange. I have the following code but it's not working because it says that the operator & is not defined for types Control, wich i use to declare my array of labels. Can someone tell me if i'm doing anything wrong? (I'm a begginer in VB.Net)

```
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
                Dim labels() As Control = {Label1, Label2, Label3, Label4, Label5, Label6, Label7, Label8, Label9, Label10, Label11, Label12, Label13, Label14, Label15, Label16, Label17, Label18, Label19, Label20, Label21, Label22,
                    Label23, Label24, Label25, Label26, Label27, Label28, Label29, Label30, Label31, Label32, Label33, Label34, Label35, Label36, Label37, Label38, Label39, Label40, Label41, Label42, Label43, Label44, Label45, Label46,
                    Label47, Label48, Label49, Label50, Label51, Label52, Label53, Label54, Label55, Label56, Label57, Label58, Label59, Label60, Label61, Label62, Label63, Label64, Label65, Label66, Label67, Label68, Label69, Label70,
                    Label71, Label72}
                Dim estado As Integer

                Try
                    con.Open()
                    For i = 0 To 71
                        Console.WriteLine(labels(i))
                        Dim sqlquery = "select IDEstado from Maquinas where IDMaquina = " & labels(i) & ""
                        Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand()
                        myCommand.Connection = con
                        myCommand.CommandText = sqlquery
                        Dim objReader As MySqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader
                        If objReader.Read = True Then
                            estado = objReader("IDEstado")

                            If estado = 1 Then
                                labels(i).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
                            ElseIf estado = 2 Then
                                labels(i).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
                            Else
                                labels(i).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkOrange
                            End If
                        End If
                        objReader.Close()
                    Next
                    con.Close()
                Finally
                End Try

            End Sub
```

Comment: Do you know on which line you're getting the error ? Possibly `Console.WriteLine(labels(i))` needs a .ToString or a .Text.

Comment: ` & labels(i) & ""`<- possibly that. Do you need to use the labels(I).Text property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `Text` property of the control while concatenating it like below else per your posted code you are actually trying to concatenate string with a control and so the error.

```
Dim sqlquery = "select IDEstado from Maquinas where IDMaquina = " & labels(i).Text & ""
```

Comment: Yes it helped. Just one more question, there are some labels that are not going green (all the machines have the state 1 right now) and when i make a console.writeline of the value the query is receiving the ones who don't are green the writeline doens't show anything. Any reason for it works in the most of the labels and don't in other few?

Comment: Am not sure I understood your question. Would be better if you post a separate question with code sample where you have trouble.

Comment: In fact what i want in the select query is something like this: Dim sqlquery = "select IDEstado from Maquinas where IDMaquina =  i " but if i put it that way it says that Unknown column 'i' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to join a Label control with a string in your sqlquery, you need to get the text from the label, see below;

Change this:

```
Dim sqlquery = "select IDEstado from Maquinas where IDMaquina = " & labels(i) & ""
```

to this:

```
Dim sqlquery = "select IDEstado from Maquinas where IDMaquina = " & labels(i).Text & ""
```